# How to add the element conditionally in `*ngFor` loop?

Tags: angular, angular5

I am looping through a `li` element. in the first `li` require to have a child as `span` element. how to achieve that?

here is my try:

```
    <ul class="country-list">
            <li *ngFor="let country of supportedCountries; let i = index ">
                    <span *ngIf="i===0" class="drop-down">{{country}}</span> {{country}}
            </li>
   </ul>
```

Comment: as per my try, I am getting 2 instant on first element both with span and without

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the NgForOf directive also has a 'first' variable:

```
<ul class="country-list">
  <li *ngFor="let country of supportedCountries; let first = first ">
     <span *ngIf="first === true" class="drop-down">{{country}}</span>      
     <ng-container *ngIf="first === false">{{country}}</ng-container>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: It give the same result what I had already, have 2 value in first `li` element

Comment: do we have other variable helper on ngFor ? maybe i have missed this point on the Documentation but i have never hear about this nice trick.

Answer (score 2):

you can use `ng-container` with no extra DOM element and every value of `i` you want:

```
<ul class="country-list">
    <li *ngFor="let country of myArray; let i = index ">
        <ng-container *ngIf="i===0">
            <span class="drop-down">salam</span> 
        </ng-container>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Doesn't work with `*ngIf` in a `ng-container` working with `[ngIf]` instead EDIT : Sorry testing in a `ng-template`

Comment: In your example, it seems you will be getting myArray.length <li> tags.  How could you make the repeated tag with the ngFor be either a div or an say in img. IOW, I am stepping thru an array and based on the array element I want a <div> or <img> the outer tag remains the same <T1 class="outer"> <div></div> <img> <img> <img> <div></div><img> <img>....</T1>  Thank you.